# Strategies for paging in Stored procedure (View or ?)

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, pagination

I have this stored procedure that returns around 100K to 1M rows, depending on the parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_doStuff
    @userId bigint = 0,
    @date datetime = null
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        ...
    from 
        ...
    order by theDate DESC;

END
```

This stored procedure is called by a Java method via jdbcTemplate, and it does the paging from there. 
However that is very slow, considering that `sp_doStuff` average execution time is 60 seconds already.

That is this `sp_doStuff` is called for every next page button the user clicks (very slow). 
Its ok for one time its 60 seconds, but for the next page it should not be. How can I implement a view (or whatever solution application) 
within this SQL code such that the `jdbcTemplate` call will not have to deal with this hundred thousand rows everytime.

**Called every time next button is clicked:**

```
String sql = "MyDB..sp_doStuff '12345', '2013-01-24'"
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new ResultSetExtractor<MyModel<Map<String, String>>>() {
        @Override
        public MyModel<Map<String, String>> extractData(ResultSet rs)
                throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                ....
        }
    });
```

Comment: A View won't help - it's just a View and will be "re-executed". And SP can't be used as the basis for an Indexed View - so that's out too. Perhaps the query - does it need to be an SP? Remember, this wreaks havoc on RA flow through! - could be sped up with analysis and appropriate indices/hints? I have *large, complicated queries* that run in just a few seconds. If not overall, perhaps it could be sped up over a range (e.g. paged each batch). Perhaps the query can be kept in the application cache? Perhaps the query could be kept in a temporary table (which is a form of a cache)?

Comment: Ok, if I use temp table, then for each query coming from the browser (from multiple users) temp table will be created for each? Multiplied by each date being queried for?

Comment: It's icky to manage, yes, but it is one approach. I would recommend first running a performance analysis on the SP and see if that query can be made "significantly faster". That is, 60 seconds seems *way too long* for a general "live view" result-set. A simple incorrect selection of a loop join for a hash join (which can be caused by lack of variable sniffing) is one perfectly easy way to confuse the query planner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you really should display all 100k rows to user on page??? It's looks crazy, real person never analize 100k rows of information in real life. It's OK if you have 1M of rows and calculate AVG of their values or smth else, but for displaying to person from SP is very bad practise. From my perspective, you should using approach with limit of result set of rows and indexes. 
Ex.:`SELECT salary, date FROM USER_SALARY t WHERE t.id = '1748' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 29799, 100;`
This request will display 100 rows (start rows position - 29800) from USER_SALARY table for user with id 1748 which ordered by day field (of course index already created by ID field)
I suppose, that above approach allow you to work with big data tables which should be displayed to user on page.

Comment: In my question, I explicitly said that the paging is done in java

Comment: If you have bad architecture code - you should change this part of code, otherwise your code will working slowly